# Android SQLite Database Exception: no such table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I am attempting to create a SQLite Database from EditText fields in my app and then display them in a listview. It appears to enter the data okay but when I go to load the listview the app crashes and in the LogCat I see the exception no such table: PatientData in my case. Any advice is welcome!

```
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
    import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_SEX = "sex";
public static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_ADDR = "address";
public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
public static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
public static final String KEY_ZIP = "zip";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PatientDB";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "PatientData";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SEX, KEY_DOB, KEY_AGE, KEY_ADDR, KEY_CITY, KEY_STATE, KEY_ZIP};

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE=
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
        + KEY_SEX + "text not null,"
        + KEY_DOB + " text not null, "
        + KEY_AGE + " integer not null,"

        // Rest  of creation:
        + KEY_ADDR + " text not null,"
        + KEY_CITY + " text not null,"
        + KEY_STATE + "text not null,"
        + KEY_ZIP + "integer not null"
        +");";
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}
public DBAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);            
        }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public long insertRecord(String name, String sex, String dob, String age, String address, String city, String zip, String state){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SEX, sex);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DOB, dob);
    initialValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDR, address);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STATE, state );
    initialValues.put(KEY_ZIP, zip);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId){
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) >0;
}
public Cursor getAllRecords(){
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException{
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
/*public Cursor getCursor() throws SQLException{
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);
    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};

    Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(db, asColumnsToReturn, null, null, null, null, "name ASC");
    return mCursor;
}*/
public String getName(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(1));
}
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String sex, String dob, String age, String address, String city, String state, String zip){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_SEX, sex);
    args.put(KEY_DOB, dob);
    args.put(KEY_ADDR, address);
    args.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    args.put(KEY_STATE, state);
    args.put(KEY_ZIP, zip);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Correct your query with below

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE=
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
    + KEY_SEX + " text not null,"
    + KEY_DOB + " text not null, "
    + KEY_AGE + " integer not null,"

    // Rest  of creation:
    + KEY_ADDR + " text not null,"
    + KEY_CITY + " text not null,"
    + KEY_STATE + " text not null,"
    + KEY_ZIP + " integer not null"
    +");";
```

You forget to add space at

```
    + KEY_SEX + "text not null," 
    + KEY_STATE + "text not null,"
    + KEY_ZIP + "integer not null"
```

Add space between `column name` and `column type`.